# Angular ng-view animation transitions

Tags: angularjs, css, transition, ng-animate, ng-view

Using angularjs 1.2, I would like to apply transition animations to my views on enter and leave. I am using 'ngAnimate' to make this possible, however the transition animation is only taking place on my home page. I've been using this [article](http://slides.com/gsklee/animation-in-angularjs-12#/7) as guide.

HTML (index.html):

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" id="outer">
    <div id="page">

    <!-- partial views -->
    <div class="page {{pageClass}}" ng-view></div>      

</body>
```

I've create a controller for each page and applied a class in an attempt to manipulate the DOM with CSS3. Is there is a better/cleaner way to do this with angular please?

AngularJS:

```
var myWebsite = angular.module('myWebsite',['ngRoute', 'duScroll','ngSanitize','ngAnimate'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl:'home.html',
            controller:'mainCtrl'
            })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl:'about.html',
            controller:'aboutCtrl'
            })
        .when('/contact',{
            templateUrl:'contact.html',
            controller:'contactCtrl'
            })
        .when('/services', {
            templateUrl:'services.html',
            controller:'servicesCtrl'
            })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl:'home.html',
            controller:'mainCtrl'
            });
})

.controller('mainCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'home';
})

.controller('aboutCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'about';
})
.controller('servicesCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'services';
})
 .controller('contactCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.pageClass = 'contact';
})
...
```

I'm using CSS in an attempt to create the slidein on enter'ng-enter' and slideout of leave 'ng-leave'. I've only applied these styles to the .about and .home, although when i view my code in Google Developer the class '.home' is not being dynamically generated via angularjs controller, but .about is being generated. I believe the animation is taking occurring on the class '.page' which is not generated dynamically.

CSS:

```
/* --- page specific animations --- */

/* home */
.page.ng-enter, .about.ng-enter{
     -webkit-animation:slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;
    animation:slideInUp 0.5s both ease-in;
    z-index: 8888; 

}

/* leave */
.page.ng-leave, .about.ng-enter{
     -webkit-animation:slideDownOut 0.5s both ease-in;
    -moz-animation:slideDownOut 0.5s both ease-in;
    animation:slideDownOut 0.5s both ease-in; 
    z-index: 9999;
}


/* --entering animation--*/

/* slide in from the bottom */
@keyframes slideInUp {
    from    { transform:translateY(100%); opacity: 1; }
    to      { transform: translateY(0); opacity: .5; }
}
@-moz-keyframes slideInUp {
    from    { -moz-transform:translateY(100%); opacity: 1;}
    to      { -moz-transform: translateY(0); opacity: .5;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideInUp {
    from    { -webkit-transform:translateY(100%); opacity: 1;}
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateY(0); opacity: .5;}
}

/* --leaving animation--*/

/* slide in from the bottom */
@keyframes slideDownOut {
    from    { transform: translateX(0%); opacity: .5; }
    to      { transform: translateY(100%); opacity: 0;}
}
@-moz-keyframes slideDownOut {  
    from    { -moz-transform: translateX(0%); opacity: .5; }
    to      { -moz-transform: translateY(100%); opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideDownOut {
    from    { -webkit-transform: translateX(0%); opacity: .5;}
    to      { -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); opacity: 0;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded angularJs and angular-Animate to version 1.3.14 using google cdn, and applied the following code that works.

I removed the multiply controllers for each view as they were not needed to accomplish this task.

**If anyone has suggestions on how to optimize this code to increase performance / speed please post your suggestions. Thank You**

I used [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vA6aomUPNw) for guidance and this [code example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bY70b3f3PpegDtpTWiKc?p=preview)

angular:

```
var myWebsite = angular.module('myWebsite',['ngRoute', 'duScroll','ngAnimate'])
.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/#', {
            templateUrl:'home.html'
            })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl:'about.html'
            })
        .when('/contact',{
            templateUrl:'contact.html'
            })
        .when('/services', {
            templateUrl:'services.html'
            })
        .otherwise({
            templateUrl:'home.html'
            });
})
```

I applied .ng-enter, .ng-leave, .ng-enter-active, .ng-leave-active, .ng-leave-stagger, .ng-enter-stagger within my CSS. These classes are dynamically applied through angular-animate and i simply used css to apply animation to each.

CSS:

```
.slide-container {
  position:relative;
}
.slide.ng-enter, .slide.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s linear all;
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  height:600px;
}

.slide.ng-enter-stagger{
    transition-delay:1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
}

.slide.ng-enter {
  z-index:100;
  top:600px;
  opacity:0;
}
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  top:0;
  opacity:1;
}

.slide.ng-leave {
  z-index:101;
  top:0;
  opacity:1;
}
.slide.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  top:-600px;
  opacity:0;
}

.slide.ng-leave-stagger{
    transition-delay:1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay:1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 1s;
    -ms-transition-delay: 1s;
}
```

Then I changed my HTML by removing the dynamic classes i was generating with angular and applied the class for my animation to the ng-view

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" id="outer">
    <div id="page">

    <!-- navigation --> 
    <ng-include src="'nav.html'"></ng-include>

    <!-- partial views -->
    <div ng-view class="slide"></div>   

    <!-- footer -->
    <ng-include src="'footer.html'"></ng-include>

</body>
```